# I am having difficulties getting my query to work correctly. Can you please assist?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been struggling with this query for weeks now, making various db changes to help make the query work correctly.

This is my continuing survey task.

The last task is to display results of surey taken by any individual.

The query is to list the each multiple choice question, followed by user's choice and the correct answer or answers depending on whether the question is checkbox question that takes more than answers as correct answers.

Then the next row is compute total questions answered, how many the user got right out of total answered and percentage of correct answers.

Here is the general layout:

```
Question                       Your Choice                    Correct Answer

Total Questions:_________    You got _X out of _X number    %Correct:____x%
```

Because of the complexity, I have broken the sql query into 3. The first query list each query. The second lists users choices and the third lists correct answers.

All filtered by SurveyId and Username

So far this is fine.

The area I am having the most difficulty is computing Total Questions, how many user got out of total questions and percentage.

Below is my query. I am supposed to give a demo of this survey this afternoon.

I hope you generous SQL geniuses can bail me out.

```
SELECT Q.QUESTION, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN A.CHOICEID IS NOT NULL 
                  AND C.ISCORRECT = 'True' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END - CASE 
                   WHEN Q.ANSWERTYPE = 'M' 
                        AND A.CHOICEID IS NOT NULL 
                        AND C.ISCORRECT = 'False' THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                 END) / ( CASE Q.ANSWERTYPE 
                            WHEN 'S' THEN 1 
                            WHEN 'M' THEN Sum(CASE 
                                                WHEN C.ISCORRECT = 'True' THEN 1 
                                                ELSE 0 
                                              END) 
                          END ) AS score 
FROM   SURVEYQUESTIONS AS Q 
       INNER JOIN SURVEY AS S 
               ON Q.SURVEYID = S.SURVEYID 
       INNER JOIN SURVEYCHOICES AS C 
               ON Q.QUESTIONID = C.QUESTIONID 
       LEFT JOIN SURVEYANSWERS AS A 
              ON A.QUESTIONID = C.QUESTIONID 
       LEFT JOIN SURVEYANSWERS AS sa 
              ON C.CHOICEID = A.CHOICEID 
                 AND A.USERNAME = @UserName 
WHERE  S.SURVEYID = @SurveyId 
GROUP  BY Q.QUESTION, 
          Q.ANSWERTYPE;
```

I will be happy to post table structures if needed.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What does AnswerType = 'M' and AnswerType = 'S' mean?

Comment: Hi @SteveFord, First, thanks a lot for your response.

Answertype ='M' means Multiple choice questions used primarily for Checkboxes. As stated, users can check one or more checkboxes.

'S' means Single choice answers. For instance, radio buttons and user checks just one answer.

If the issue I am having is just radio button choices, it would have been much easier to manage.

Computing Checkbox answers where user could check one or more is hard.

Comment: I'd be curious to see the table structure...

Comment: @ChidiOkeh I think we need to see some sample data, what results you expect to get and what results your current query returns along with the table structures. A SQLFiddle example would be great.

Comment: @SteveFord, is there a SQL Server version of SQLFiddle? Just trying to create the tables is giving an error that I need to use MySQL syntax.

Nevermind, I see it.

I am doing it now.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh just click the dropdown where it says MySQL 5.5.32 and select MS SQL Server. Make sure you put your setup schema and data commands in the left hand box and press build schema, then type your results query in the rhs and share the SQL Fiddle URL

Comment: @SteveFord, I am running into issues. Fiddle is telling me my code to create the tables and insert data is too large. That I need to limit to 8000 characters.

Not sure how to get this done though.

Comment: Hi @ChidiOkeh, you don't need to load all your data, just a representative sample, for instance 2-3 questions and their corresponding answers for 1 or 2 users

Comment: @SteveFord, thank you very much for your patience sir.

Here is the fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ca40/2

As you can see, the layout shows Question and the Score.

Please see preferred data and layout on my original post above.

Also, we expect the score to show something like 0.00% or 0.67 percent or 100% depending on correct answers, especially with the checkboxes.

Comment: Hey @SteveFord, please don't tell me you made go through all that work of putting stuff in sqlFiddle and you disappear?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh in your SQLFiddle example you only have an example of one surveyanswer, can you provide a few more and update your question to show what results you expect from your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQLFiddle example only had one survey answer which wasn't part of survey 10. I have added one correct answer to the new SQL Fiddle. I think the query at the end gets you what you want and is very simple.

SQL Fiddle details below:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SurveyQuestions]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyQuestions](
    [QuestionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SurveyID] [int] NULL,
    [Question] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [AnswerType] [char](1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [QuestionOrder] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyQuestions_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [QuestionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ON
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (8, 10, N'Archaeological studies of the Indus Valley cities of Harappa and Mohenjo-Daro show evidence of.', N'S', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (9, 10, N'Between 1540 and 1580, what happened to the native population of Central Mexico?', N'M', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (11, 9, N'What is Avalon?', N'S', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (13, 8, N'What is your quest?', N'S', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (14, 11, N'How do you like this video', N'S', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (15, 11, N'Your favorite movie', N'M', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] ([QuestionID], [SurveyID], [Question], [AnswerType], [QuestionOrder]) VALUES (16, 10, N'George Boole is a:', N'M', 3)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyQuestions] OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Survey]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Survey](
    [SurveyID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Survey] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SurveyID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Survey] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Survey] ([SurveyID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (8, N'The Bridge of Death', N'Test your knowledge of this classic scene from a classic movie.')
INSERT [dbo].[Survey] ([SurveyID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (9, N'What''s Next at Microsoft?', N'Reading your blogs?  Test your knowledge about what''s baking in Microsoft''s oven.')
INSERT [dbo].[Survey] ([SurveyID], [Title], [Description]) VALUES (10, N'Movie History', N'Test your knowledge of movies')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Survey] OFF


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SurveyChoices]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyChoices](
    [ChoiceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Choice] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [IsCorrect] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyChoices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ChoiceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ON
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (56, 8, N'dynastic rule', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (57, 8, N'monotheism', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (58, 8, N'social equality', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (59, 8, N'urban planning', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (60, 9, N'It decreased by approximately 6 million people.', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (61, 9, N'It increased to a high of 26 million people.', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (62, 9, N'It increased by approximatley 2 million people per year.', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (63, 9, N'It decreased to 8 million people.', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (64, 11, N'Build UI with XAML', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (65, 11, N'Next Generation Web Services', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (66, 11, N'Next Version of Office', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (67, 11, N'Codename for Xbox 360', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (89, 13, N'To seek the Holy Grail', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (90, 13, N'To seek the Holy Hand Grenade', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (91, 13, N'To see the Knight that says Ni!', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (92, 13, N'To sing the Ballad of Brave Sir Robin', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (93, 14, N'Bad', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (94, 14, N'Ok', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (95, 14, N'Good', 0)
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] ([ChoiceID], [QuestionID], [Choice], [IsCorrect]) VALUES (97, 14, N'Excellent', 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyChoices] OFF

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SurveyAnswers]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SurveyAnswers](
    [AnswerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [QuestionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ChoiceID] [int] NULL,
    [ChoiceText] [varchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SurveyAnswers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AnswerID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON)
)
END
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyAnswers] ON
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyAnswers] ([AnswerID], [QuestionID], [ChoiceID], [ChoiceText], [UserName]) VALUES (51, 14, 95, NULL, N'John.Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[SurveyAnswers] ([AnswerID], [QuestionID], [ChoiceID], [ChoiceText], [UserName]) VALUES (52, 9, 62, NULL, N'John.Doe')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[SurveyAnswers] OFF
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalQuestions,
       COUNT(SA.AnswerID) AS TotalCorrect,
       CAST(COUNT(SA.AnswerID) AS Float) / 
            SUM(CASE WHEN SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 As Percentage
FROM
SurveyQuestions SQ
INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC
    ON SQ.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID
LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers SA
  ON SA.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID 
    AND SA.ChoiceID = SC.ChoiceID
    AND SA.UserName = 'John.Doe'
WHERE SC.IsCorrect = 1 
  AND SQ.SurveyID = 10
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/1/0)**:

```
| TOTALQUESTIONS | TOTALCORRECT |      PERCENTAGE |
---------------------------------------------------
|              3 |            1 | 33.333333333333 |
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You are a lifesaver. I spent entire weekend cracking my head and I have a demo this morning. It wasn't pleasant but you changed all that. You also made much simpler.

Do you still need more answers for testing?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh if your happy I'm happy, you might want to put up some more sample data for anyone stumbling across this in the future

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to give you some idea on how it could be done, though I'm not exactly sure about the column names and resulting column:

```
with SingleAnswers (QuestionID,SurveyID,Username,TotalSingle)
as(
Select 
    SQ.QuestionID,S.SurveyID, Username,count(*)TotalSingle 
from 
    SurveyAnswers SA 
join  
    surveychoices SC on SA.choiceId = SC.choiceId
join
    surveyquestions SQ on SQ.QuestionID = SC.QuestionID
JOIN 
    Survey S ON SQ.SurveyID =  S.SurveyID
where 
    SA.ChoiceID is Not Null and username = @UserName and SC.iscorrect='True' and SQ.AnswerType='S'
group by
    SQ.QuestionID,S.SurveyID, Username)

,MultipleAnswers (QuestionID,SurveyID,Username,TotalMultiple)
as(
Select 
    SQ.QuestionID,S.SurveyID, Username,count(*)TotalMultiple
from 
    SurveyAnswers SA 
join  
    surveychoices SC on SA.choiceId = SC.choiceId
join
    surveyquestions SQ on SQ.QuestionID = SC.QuestionID
JOIN 
    Survey S ON SQ.SurveyID =  S.SurveyID
where 
    SA.ChoiceID is Not Null and username = @UserName and SC.iscorrect='True' and SQ.AnswerType='M'
group by
    SQ.QuestionID,S.SurveyID, Username)

select 
    count(Q.QuestionID) TotalQuestions,'You got '+Convert(Varchar,sum(TotalSingle) +sum(TotalMultiple))+'out of  '+Convert(Varchar,count(Q.QuestionID))+' number' FinalOutCome,(count(Q.QuestionID)/sum(TotalSingle)+sum(TotalMultiple)) Correct_Percent
from 
    surveyquestions AS Q
JOIN 
    Survey AS S ON Q.SurveyID = S.SurveyID
LEFT JOIN
    SingleAnswers SA ON SA.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID AND SA.SurveyID =  S.SurveyID
LEFT JOIN
    MultipleAnswers MA ON MA.QuestionID = Q.QuestionID AND SA.SurveyID =  S.SurveyID
```

Comment: I will try your code shortly.

I am trying to get the fiddle thing setup.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have errors with your code. It says:

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression or an xmlnamespaces clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Please try now, I've made some changes.

Comment: now getting `incorrect syntax near ANS line 42.` Did you mean to write AND?

If yes, then the following are new errors:

`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'TotalMultiple'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
Invalid column name 'TotalMultiple'.`

Comment: there were couple of spelling mistakes, I've fixed it. Please try now.

Comment: I see 3 No Column Name columns. What are those?

Your query is very confusing but I appreciate your efforts though.

Comment: There are 3 parts of the query. In the first part I'm getting the count of Answers which are correct and Single choice, in the second part of the query I'm getting count of answers which are correct and multiple choice, In the third and final part of the query I'm taking a count of all the questions, and joining it with first and second part of the query with the column Survey Id and Question ID. Also as I've used CTE, you have to run all the queries together. Please let me know if you are getting any error or you are looking for something else.

Comment: did you make any additonal changes.

What I am saying is that the No Column names are confusing me.

Can you please add alias to the No Column names so I understand what they represent?

Comment: I've added the column names now.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are trying to do.

We don't need SingleAnswers and MultipleAnswers.

We we need are: TotalQuestions like you have it, how many the user got right like Gotgot 3 out of 6 and then the Percent correct like you have it.

Are these possible?

Comment: Done. Please check, and I hope this is what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: we are getting the TotalQuestions correct.

However, FinalOutCome and Percent_Correct are NULL and should not be.

Two of those questions are Multiple Choice (Checkbox) answers.

One of those, user gets 1 out 2 correct in each. So, they should be 50% correct. One of those answers are single choice like Radio button choices and the user gets the correct answer.

This is where I am lost. A total of 3 questions. Since user gets 2 out of 4 correct in checkbox and 1 out of 1 correct in radio choice, shoule be 3 out of 5 and whatever the percentage is.

Is it doable?